# HTML: p text overflows when parent component has display:flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have this code:

```
<div className="display-flex">
  <div className="test-border">
    <p className="flex-child">
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

These are the classes definitions:

```
.display-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.test-border {
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

The problem is the class `display-flex` makes the text overflow the border:
[image]
Adding the class `flex-child` did not solve this issue. It's as if it doesn't work when I add the class `display-flex`.
Any idea how to solve this?

---

**NOTE 1:**
I noticed this problem only occurs if `p` element is inside another `div`. So in this example it can be solved by just removing the parent `div` of the `p` element. But, in my project I cannot do that because there are other elements within that `div`:

```
<div className="display-flex">
  {/* <div className="test-border"> */}
    <p className="flex-child">
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </p>
  {/* </div> */}
</div>
```

So this is the result:
[image]

**And that's what I want to achieve but without removing the parent `div`.**

Comment: You need to break the word....adding ridiculously long words is not really informative.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here, please clarify what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Paulie_D check out the note I just added

Comment: min-width:0 to the flex item

Comment: @TemaniAfif didn't work

Comment: it does: https://jsfiddle.net/opars9q1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Great! Thank you! That solved my problem :))